# Почему "тепло оделся" говорят, а "холодно оделся" — нет?

Tags: стилистика, лексическая-сочетаемость

Вместо *"холодно оделся"* говорят *"легко оделся".*

Можно разобраться, почему так сложилось в языке, или можно только констатировать это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Люди одеваются, чтобы согреться, чтобы им **было теплее (а не холоднее)**. Если мало одежды, то легко оделся, а если одежды много, то оделся тепло.

Comment: А точно, спасибо, Sibylla!)

Answer (score 1):

"Прохладно оделся" говорят ([пример](https://books.google.ru/books?id=8fS6AAAAQBAJ&pg=PT24&lpg=PT24&dq=%22%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9%22&source=bl&ots=EPE89_HMhe&sig=D_bI9eq9DQtLASUJAy3AVpHGPt4&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwilmtu3uv3OAhWBoiwKHSOlAhwQ6AEIITAB#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9%22&f=false)). Еще одна градация тут излишняя. Вот почему выбран такой вариант, не знаю. Возможно просто потому, что "прохладный" - более точный антоним "теплому", а "холодный" - "жаркому". Предки наши как-то лучше всё это различали.

Comment: Спасибо! Мне всё-таки кажется, что с натяжкой можно "принять" (считать, что так можно сказать) "прохладно одетый/одеться", но всё-таки как-то это не очень звучит. Возможно, я и ошибаюсь... Хорошо бы ещё услышать мнений. ;)

Comment: Нет, звучит вполне себе нормально. У меня даже мысли нет ни о какой натяжке. Толстому тут модно верить, да ладно бы только ему... Лучше расскажите, Как вам длинную ссылку удалось засунуть в тэг. Обычно это кончается крахом, я даже перестал пытаться. Единственное, что могу предположить, та ни одного хитрого символа не попало каким-то провиденьем... Или починили функционал нам не сказавши...

Comment: А-а, это Толстой, даже не заметил. И, к стыду своему, даже не слышал о таком произведении.(( Любопытно тогда. А насчёт гиперссылки, так я просто вырезал текст ссылки, написал "пример", выделил его, нажал на кнопочку создания гиперссылки и вставил в нужное поле скопированное. Вроде всё просто. У меня почему-то и раньше проблем с этим не было. Может, не работало до того, как я тут появился (чуть меньше года назад)?